# Invoke a function without parentheses javascript

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

So I wrote this String function to add stuff to each word in a sentence

```
String.prototype.addStuff = function() {
    return this.replace(/ /g, "-stuff ") + "-stuff"
}
```

I was told there was a way to invoke this function on a string without using parentheses.
Anyone know how?

I tried wrapping the function declaration in parentheses and adding a pair to the end:

```
String.prototype.liu = (function() {
    return this.replace(/ /g, "-liu ") + "-liu"
})();
```

But that didn't work :/

Comment: You would never wrap it in parenthesis. You would call your function externally.

Comment: [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: If you “were told”, then why don’t you ask the person you _were told_ by …? (Only thing I can think of, is a `toString` method that will get called automatically when the string is output somewhere.)

Comment: Including a formal parameter list in parenthesis after an expression that resolves to a function (e.g. a variable name or function expression) causes the function to be called. There is no other way without [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fset), which aren't generally available. See [ECMA-262 §11.2.3 Function Calls](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3).

Comment: See [Invoking a function without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949554/invoking-a-function-without-parentheses) for lots of ways to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can, with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and providing an *accessor descriptor*:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'liu', {
    get: function() {
        return this.replace(/ /g, "-liu ") + "-liu"
    }
});

"foo".liu
```

Although I don't know why you'd want to do that.

Comment: Only in ES5 hosts though, e.g. IE 8 is out. :-(

Comment: Thanks, that works and it's cool. I was asked it in an interview and was completely stumped. I wrote the String function to add -liu to the end of each word and then my interviewer asked me, "what if I want to be able to call it like so: "hello my name is".liu
and it would return "hello-liu my-liu name-liu is-liu"

Answer (score 0):

#### Potentially, you can't just wrap a whole `function` into a `prototype` to auto call.

Now, what you **can do**, is define a shared `function` *within* that `prototype`.

Of course, you have to call it, **but that beats no answer at all.**

[Good Read on how prototypical inheritance works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Now, you **COULD** do:

```
yourFunc.prototype.call('yourFunc');
```

But you'd have to format it properly to make it work.

Comment: That still uses `()` though.

Comment: How would I do this one if my function is called **addStuff**?  addStuff.prototype.call('addStuff') ?