# JavaScript function is invoked without parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm writing an API and I need to execute a ternary inside a "getter" function for various fields. This works fine but I don't want the end user to have to use parentheses when accessing these fields.

Strangely the getter code actually executes when I access the field **without** the parentheses but I'm wondering if this is normal for javascript or if this is browser dependent? Currently using Firefox 31.

This works:
`var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js(); // Note I'm using the parentheses`

This also works even without parentheses. How?:
`var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js; // Note the lack of parentheses`

Example API:

```
var Scripts = (function () {
    function Scripts() {
    }
    Scripts.isProduction = false;
    Scripts.Url = "/Scripts";
    Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js = function () {
        return Scripts.isProduction ? Scripts.Url + "/jQuery_1_11_1.min.js" : Scripts.Url + "/jQuery_1_11_1.js";
    }
    return Scripts;
})();
var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js();
var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js; /// why does this work?
```

Comment: `var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js;` makes `theScript` hold the function. Using which, you can call `console.log(theScript());` later. In the `var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js();`, the variable `theScript` holds the string, which is the result of the function.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. Try `console.log(theScript)` after each of them and you'll see the difference.

Comment: How are you testing whether or not it "works"? With your code, that shouldn't call the function.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wuzimere/1/edit?html,output (aka What Barmar said).

Comment: When you don't have the parentheses, you're not calling the function, you're just returning the function itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568499/invoke-a-function-without-parentheses-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Doh, had some left over code elsewhere that made it look like it was working but in fact it's just returns the function object itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This also works even without parentheses. How?:
>
> `var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js; // Note the lack of parentheses`

No, it doesn't. The line executes just fine, but it doesn't *call* `Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js`, it just sets the value of `theScript` to a reference to the function `Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js`.

There are only <s>two</s> *four* (as of ES2015) ways I know of to call a function without parentheses:

1. Define the property on `Scripts` as an ES5 getter. Here's the ES5 syntax for doing that:

   ```
   Object.defineProperty(Scripts, "jQuery_1_11_1_js", {
       get: function() {
           return Scripts.isProduction ? Scripts.Url + "/jQuery_1_11_1.min.js" : Scripts.Url + "/jQuery_1_11_1.js";
       }
   });
   ```

   Now, the line

   ```
   var theScript = Scripts.jQuery_1_11_1_js;
   ```

   ...will call that anonymous function we defined as the getter for the property.

   Unfortunately, you [can't do that in IE8](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.defineProperty). In IE8 (bizarrely), `Object.defineProperty` can only create properties on DOM elements, not normal objects. IE9 supports it properly.
2. Just for completeness, there is a second way, with `new`:

   ```
   var foo = new Foo;
   ```

   ...which is equivalent to

   ```
   var foo = new Foo();
   ```

   But of course, you don't want to do that unless `Foo` is meant to be a constructor function, as it creates an object to pass to `Foo` as `this`.
3. Calling a *tag function*:

   ```
   someFunction`template contents here`;
   ```

   That doesn't look like a function call, but it is. It parses the template, evalutes any token expressions, and passes the raw form of the template (an array of strings with an added `raw` property, subsequent arguments for the token substitutions) into `someFunction`. Whereas `` someFunction(`template contents here`) `` would evaluate the template, evaluate any token expressions, and substitute them into the template producing a string, and then pass the string into `someFunction`. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates).
4. Do just about anything on a [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), since all the fundamental object operations (getting properties, setting properties, defining properties, getting its prototype, etc., etc.) can be *trapped* on proxies, generating a call to a trap handler.

Comment: yea testing error, however your first option works great. thanks!