# Calling a Method Using Two Different Ways

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript and Node.js and am learning OOP and came across two ways of calling a method.

My code:

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.fName = name;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
    console.log("Hello, I am " + this.fName);
}

var person1 = new Person("mike");
person1.sayHello();

var helloFunction = person1.sayHello;
helloFunction.call(person1);
```

Output:

```
Hello, I am mike
Hello, I am mike
```

Both uses produce the same results. Is there a situation where one version would be more proper than the other? Are there any advantages/disadvantages to the two calls?

Comment: `Proper` way of doing things is debatable. It all depends on your use case. Try to follow one convention only unless you can't avoid it.

Comment: As a side note, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949554/invoking-a-function-without-parentheses)

Comment: The second way is useful if you need to call `sayHello` bound to another `this` context that contains a `fName` property also. Other than that, try to follow the first way you've found and also have a look at the `class` and `extends` keywords introduced in 2015.

Comment: @Amit I will look into those, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a situation where one version would be more proper than the other?

You'd almost exclusivity use the *normal*, `func()` when calling a function. Using `func.call()` is not meant to be used without special reason, particularly, using a specific object as the `this` value.

Arbitrary usage of non-standard coding patterns creates unreadable, unmaintainable, bug prone code.

Comment: This.  Using .call makes me think that the function is an entirely different object with a method called call() that i'm simply not aware of on first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Both are legit. It depends on what endgame is for the results. Using `.call` is useful when you want to reuse a method from one object on another.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would use `person1.sayHello()`. It's more concise and easier to read.

Where you would want to use `sayHello.call` is if the object has the `fName` property but does not itself have a `sayHello` method. For example:

```
var helloFunction = person1.sayHello;
var pseudoPerson = { fName: "shadow mike" };
helloFunction.call(pseudoPerson); // "Hello, I am shadow mike"
```