# Regex - matching any function name, with exception of keywords

Tags: javascript, regex

Just to start off, I'm using [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) as reference (writing the highlighting in Javascript). And a very important thing is: **I'm not writing syntax highlighting for Javascript.** I'm writing for a language called gLUA, which is a very strict type of language, example code can be found [here](https://maurits.tv/data/garrysmod/wiki/wiki.garrysmod.com/index3edb.html).

I have a project I'm using PrismJS for, with its syntax highlighting features. I had to make my own with regex (code below), and now I'm stuck at one part, namely two selectors clashing one another. Syntax highlight looks [like this](https://i.gyazo.com/9806bc86b21979ed004bf7b0731148a8.png) with both rules.

If I remove the `(` from the punctuation regex selection, everything turns out [fine](https://i.gyazo.com/3db785d80fabb22c2bf5e7862762c5ef.png) (except the parenthesis, that is...)

I need the `(?=\()` selection for the function, or else I'm going to have a really bad time working around it. I've already spend several hours figuring it out, so I'd rather not poke on it. Are there any other workarounds? I love the gray color on the parentheses...

```
// DONE
'directive': /@(name.*|model.*|inputs|outputs|persist|trigger|autoupdate)/,

//DONE
'type': /\b(angle|array|bone|complex|entity|matrix[24]?|number|quaternion|ranger|string|table|vector[24]?|wirelink)(?!\()\b/ig,

//DONE
'keyword': /\b((else)?if|else|for(each)?|while|break|continue|local|switch|case|default|function|return)\b/g,

//ERROR - CLASHING WITH FUNCTION BECAUSE OF "("
'punctuation': /[()\[\]{};:,]/,

//DONE
'operator': /[-+=*/%]/,

//DONE WITH MARGIN OF ERROR - SINGLE POUND CONSUMES NEXT LINE IF NO COMMENT IS ADDED AFTER POUND
'comment': /#([^\[].*?|\[[\s\S]*?]#)\b/g,

//DONE WITH MARGIN OF ERROR
'variable': /\b[A-Z]\w*/,

//DONE
'constant': /_[A-Z0-9_]+/,

//ERROR - CLASHING WITH THE PUNCTUATION "(" BECAUSE OF SELECTION (?=\() IN REGEX
'function': /\b(?!(else)?if|else|for(each)?|while|break|continue|local|switch|case|default|function|return)([a-z]\w*)(?=\()/,

//DONE
'number': /\b[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b/,

//DONE
'string': {
    pattern: /("|')(\\(?:\r\n|[\s\S])|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/ig,
    greedy: true
}
```

Comment: don't know about the whole thing, but `...keyword... (?=\()` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Sharp eye there, the `'keyword': ...` shouldn't have `(?=\()`, but rather just a `\b` so that `case`, `break` and `local` can be highlighted too

Comment: It is much more complex than that: a function does not need to have parentheses following it, as functions can be passed around, just like other objects. It's only when you *invoke* one that there will be parentheses (and even then you can [invoke functions without using parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949554/invoking-a-function-without-parentheses)). BTW, such parentheses can have white space around them.

Comment: I've forgot to mention an important thing - what I'm writing syntax highlighting for is a very strict language where: 1. you cannot pass around functions, 2. Variables must be defined when declared, and they must start with a capital letter, 3. this language has far less functionality than your good old Javascript. The only thing I'm struggling with is the regex for `functions` clash with `punctuation`