# How do I add a getter method to the built in String object?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, built-in

I trying to add a getter method to String so that it can be called like so:

```
'make me bold'.bold
```

Without parentheses. Here is how I'm trying to define the function, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949617/929321).

```
String.prototype.defineProperty(window, 'bold', { get: function (input) {
  return ('</b>'+input+'</b>');
}});
```

It says that defineProperty isn't a function though. Doesn't work if i take out prototype either. It looks possible to do with 'String.prototype.**defineGetter**' but says it's deprecated:

```
String.prototype.__defineGetter__('bold', function (input) {
  return ('</b>'+this+'</b>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Object.defineProperty:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'bold', { get: function (input) {
  return ('</b>'+this+'</b>');
}});
```

Comment: I get it now. Thought object was a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add that function to the prototype instead:**

```js
String.prototype.bold = function () {
  return ('</b>' + this + '</b>');
};

console.log('make me bold'.bold())
console.log('Ele from SO'.bold())
```

Comment: I think he means to call it without parentheses

Comment: @baao yes, but this is an alternative.  I mean, can help anyone else.

Comment: I think it even makes more sense... :-)