# Calling a function without braces, but using template string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

A function in JS can be called in the very strange way:

```
[1,2,3].join``
 -> "123"
```

Could somebody explain how it works "under the hood" or provide a link to some explanations?

Comment: The two backticks make it work somehow, I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Oh nice, it does work! Would also like to know why

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949554/invoking-a-function-without-parentheses and see example *5.* in the accepted answer

Comment: To clarify: You shouldn't be calling "normal" functions this way. There are special functions that should be called this way. E.g. `String.raw` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: I think this is a valid question regarding the "under the hood" part. The other answers merely address what it is and how it can be used but not who it works. I'd like to know that, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)  call the function that precedes them, which in this case is `join`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referring [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which  allow you to parse template literals with a function & first argument of a tag function is related to the expression. Here `join` is the tag function

```js
console.log([1,2,3].join`,`)
```

Comment: I still don't understand why this works. And I can't find anywhere this documented...

Comment: @avcajaraville Did you search for the heading "tagged templates" in the linked page?

Comment: @avcajaraville: It works for the same reasons that `foo()` calls `foo`: This is a specific language feature.

Comment: Oki doky... 10 years of JS experience... never saw this one :D

Comment: @avcajaraville: It was introduced with template literals in ES2015.

Answer (score -4):

(**Always**) Check MDN web docs for enlightenment:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

> The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating
>   all of the elements in an array (...) separated by commas or a
>   specified separator string.

Comment: This doesn't explain how it's working without `()` after the function name.

Comment: SORRY, maybe this helps:
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)

Comment: @JulioSa You can always [edit] your answer and fix it :)

Comment: @JulioSa That link is in all the other answers already.