# What's the differences between foo("123") and foo`123`?

Tags: javascript, function, templates, ecmascript-6

For a function like this. There are two ways to invoke the foo funciton.

```
function foo(){
   console.log(arguments);
}
foo(123);  // a normal way to invoke a function.
foo`123`;  // also a way to invoke a function.
```

I want to know the differences about the two way to invoke a function in details.
And the usages of the second way to invoke a function.

Comment: The second is called a tagged template literal, or a tagged function call. The difference is what arguments the function receives: In your first example, it receives a single argument that's a number (`123`). In your second example it receives a single argument that's an array containing a string (`["123"]`). The array also has an extra property on it called `raw`. The purpose of tagged template literals is that they let you build useful things from the component parts of the template. If you had substitutions in the template (```foo`123 ${x}`;```), `foo` would receive additional ...

Comment: ...arguments with those substitution values.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into tag functions and template literals in Chapter 10 of my new book. See my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: *"There are two ways to invoke the foo funciton "* [Invoking a function without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949617)