# Function call inside template with variable interpolation

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS templates and found the following example:

```
function hash(a, b) {
    return a + "##" + b;
}
let count = 3;
let a = `foo ${hash ` bar ${count} baz`}`;
console.log(a);
```

result is : `foo  bar , baz##3`

Could anyone explain:

1. Why hash function is called without using parentheses -`()`?
2. This result - `foo  bar , baz##3`?

Comment: `hash` is called as tag function where the template literal defines the arguments. See [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). Note that a function can be called without parentheses [in many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35949554/5459839).

Comment: @trincot Hash function has two arguments - `a` and `b`. Could you explain what is the first arg and what is the second one for ` bar ${count} baz`?

Comment: It's all in the docs I referred to. The template literal is broken into its parts. In this case `[" bar ", " baz "]` (first arg), and the interpolated parts follow (the value 3 in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash` is being used as a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). When a function is called with ``` `` ```, the first argument is an array of the constant string values in the template literal. The other arguments are the values of the expressions in `${}`.

In this case, the parameter `a` in `hash` is `[' bar ', ' baz']`, and `b` is `3` (the value of the variable `count`). When an array is concatenated with a string, `toString()` is implicitly called, with joins the elements together with a comma, so the result is  `bar , baz##3`, which gets interpolated into the template literal assigned to the variable `a`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The hash function is called without parentheses because it's used as a "tag" for the template literal. This syntax allows the hash function to process the template literal's parts and values.
2. The result "foo bar , baz##3" is formed because the hash function combines the string parts and values from the template literal, adding "##" between them.